# Making a Multipart HTTP POST request with @PartMap or any multipart equivalent to @FieldMap

Tags: android, http-post, httprequest, okhttp, retrofit2

I need to make a file upload along with a `JSON Object` of Strings using `form-data POST`, with my interface shown below:

```
public interface uploadService {
     @Multipart
     @POST
     Call<Void> uploadPhoto(@Part("photo") File file,
            @PartMap Map<String, Object> params);
}
```

I'm having the error `End of Line 1 at Column 1`, my `Callback` proceeds to the `OnError(...)` method. In short my HTTP Request does not succeed. I was wondering where I went wrong.

Answers are very much appreciated.

**PS:** Please don't suggest me to use `MultipartEntity extends HttpEntity` I've read that this is deprecated now. Thanks!

Comment: share your log cat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following is working for me

**Interface**

```
@Multipart
@POST("user/upload")
Call<JsonElement> upload(@PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> params);, user.getToken());
```

**Send data and image as follows**

```
LinkedHashMap<String, RequestBody> mp= new LinkedHashMap<>();
RequestBody userId = RequestBody.create(
                        okhttp3.MediaType.parse("text/plain"), user.getUserId());
RequestBody userToken = RequestBody.create(
                        okhttp3.MediaType.parse("text/plain"), user.getToken());

//Instead of "text/plain" you can also send Json
mp.put("user_id", userId);
mp.put("token", userToken);


avatarFile = new File(uri.getPath());

RequestBody fileBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/gif"), avatarFile);

mp.put("files\"; filename=\"image.gif\"", fileBody);
```

Comment: Thank you as well for answering my questions @penguin! I'll test your answer tomorrow too and I will let you and NIPHIN how it turned out! :)

Answer (score 1):

PartMap alone could be sufficient for multipart.
use

```
 @Multipart
    @POST("api/registration")
    Call<UserDetails> registerUser (@Header("Content-Length") long contentLength, @PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> params);
```

you can create a Requestody to hold file like

```
RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
```

and add it to partmap.

`Map<String, RequestBody> params;` // create and add all types of requestbody to this map.
 you could calculate the content length by

```
 long contentLength = 0;
        Iterator iterator = params.entrySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
            try {
                contentLength = contentLength + ((RequestBody)pair.getValue()).contentLength();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

. If you want to listen to progress of file uploading then you could extend the RequestBody to give out info about the progress.

```
public class ProgressRequestBody extends RequestBody {

private File file;
private ProgressListener listener;
private int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 4084;

@Override
public MediaType contentType() {
    return MediaType.parse("image/*");
}

//The constructor
public ProgressRequestBody(final File file, final ProgressListener listener) {
    this.file = file;
    this.listener = listener;
}

//The method to overide
@Override
public void writeTo(BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
    long fileLength = file.length();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
    long total = 0;
    try {
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            this.listener.onProgress(total, fileLength);
            total += read;
            sink.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
}

//A simple callback
public interface ProgressListener {
    void onProgress(final long current, final long max);
}
```

}

and use it to wrap the file like

```
 public static RequestBody toImageRequestBody(File file, ProgressListener progressListener) {
        ProgressRequestBody progressRequestBody = new ProgressRequestBody(file, progressListener);
        return progressRequestBody;
    }
```

Keep it as a bonus ;)

Comment: Thanks NIPHIN! I'll test this answer tomorrow! :)